# What is the inverse of cellstr()?

Tags: matlab

I have:

```
S = ['abc '; 'defg'; 'hi  '];  % S is a 3x4 char
c = cellstr(S)                 % c is a 3x1 cell

c = 

    'abc'
    'defg'
    'hi'
```

How can I get S from c? That is to say, what is the inverse of `cellstr()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`char(c)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html):

```
S = ['abc '; 'defg'; 'hi  '];  % S is a 3x4 char
c = cellstr(S)                 % c is a 3x1 cell

c = 

    'abc'
    'defg'
    'hi'

S2 = char(c)                        % S2 is a 3x4 char 
all(all(S == S2))

ans =

     1                            % S and S2 are identical
```